# sync Django urls with Nginx location matcher

Tags: django, nginx, server, reverse-proxy

As I'm adding new sever endpoints (Django) I need to manually update the server location matcher in 
the proxy server (Nginx)

Is there an automatic way to sync nginx.conf with urls.py?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? nginx should just be forwarding the requests on to Django.

Comment: I'm adding services like /api, /admin, etc.

Comment: So why do you need to do anything in nginx?  That should all be done in Django.

Comment: cause in Nginx is the reverse proxy for both Djagno and React dev server and I need to router the traffic based on the url

Comment: But you don't do that per route. You do that once and proxy all requests.

Comment: @DanielRoseman just now noticed it's you, thanks for all the your answers! I owe you! I'm adding routes from time to time I just thought maybe I can auto. it. but you are right I'll just move to a more generalize patterns in the location matcher.

Answer (score 0):

it's depends on how you work.

you can create some rules on your nginx for subdomains or urls like

everything that have admin.xxxxx -> send to my python

or xxxxx/admin -> send to my python

and then you don't need to change your nginx config everytime that you create a new resources.

But if you don't have any pattern and you want to routing via nginx, and you need to change locations everytime, you need to reload nginx.